# Increase expiry time (Cookie)

Tags: c#, .net, cookie-authentication

we authenticate using the below approach, I am trying to figure out how I can increase the Expiry value in HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext when the user goes to a specific end point?

```
                var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    AllowRefresh = true,                   
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2), 
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,                    
                    RedirectUri = "sign-in"                  
                };

                await httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                 CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                 new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                 authProperties);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just calling `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync` again with an updated `ExpuiresUtc`. It worked as expected.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).